# multiply large no. in array

Tags: java

multiply any 2 numbers. The numbers can be extremely large (i.e. run into hundreds of digits) and are provided as strings.

The expected output is a string which represents the product of the two numbers.
example-

```
multiply("268435456","524288")="140737488355328"
multiply("12321412423524534534543","0")="0"
```

Comment: and the question is ?

Comment: I would say use `BigInteger` but I'm guessing it's an assignment and you're not supposed to use `BigInteger`?

Comment: It might be a bit late to ask this, now that the question has already been answered; but what have you tried, and what went wrong?  A question for Stack Overflow is supposed to demonstrate that you've at least tried to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: This has the smell of homework or some other form of "learning exercise".  I'm sure most of the readership is *capable* of coming up with a solution (that doesn't use `BigInteger` or `BigDecimal`) but that defeats the purpose.  The point of a learning exercise is that **YOU** do the programming, and learn in the process.

Answer (score 2):

Use BigDecimal, which has a [multiply](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#multiply%28java.math.BigDecimal%29) method and a constructor which takes a `String`. It also contains corresponding `toString()` and `toPlainString()` methods to get your result as a string.

(If the numbers are always whole numbers, then use BigInteger instead.)